# Unclear message on clang-tidy

Tags: visual-studio, logging, clang-tidy

I run `clang-tidy` on a folder and it shows

```
Use -header-filter=.* to display errors from all non-system headers. Use -system-headers to display errors from system headers as well.
Found compiler error(s).
```

But it did not show additional message on the details of the error. Btw, log file is also not produced. What could be the way to inspect the error?

Comment: Is the file compilable? Have you followed clang-tidy advice: Use `-header-filter=.*` to display errors from all non-system headers?

Answer (score 0):

### Message: "Use -header-filter=..."

The message:

```
Use -header-filter=.* to display errors from all non-system headers. Use -system-headers to display errors from system headers as well.
```

means that there were some findings that were not shown because they
were in a file that is not the primary source file and that did not
match the header filter setting.

The message is produced at
[ClangTidyMain.cpp:290](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/llvmorg-16.0.6/clang-tools-extra/clang-tidy/tool/ClangTidyMain.cpp#L290):

```
if (Stats.ErrorsIgnoredNonUserCode)
    llvm::errs() << "Use -header-filter=.* to display errors from all "
                    "non-system headers. Use -system-headers to display "
                    "errors from system headers as well.\n";
```

The `ErrorsIgnoredNonUserCode` counter is incremented at
[ClangTidyDiagnosticConsumer.cpp:309](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/llvmorg-16.0.6/clang-tools-extra/clang-tidy/ClangTidyDiagnosticConsumer.cpp#L309):

```
} else if (!LastErrorRelatesToUserCode) {
  ++Context.Stats.ErrorsIgnoredNonUserCode;
  Errors.pop_back();               // <------- discards the finding
```

The `LastErrorRelatesToUserCode` flag is initially `false`, but can be
set to `true` at
[ClangTidyDiagnosticConsumer.cpp:547](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/llvmorg-16.0.6/clang-tools-extra/clang-tidy/ClangTidyDiagnosticConsumer.cpp#L547):

```
LastErrorRelatesToUserCode = LastErrorRelatesToUserCode ||
                             Sources.isInMainFile(Location) ||
                             getHeaderFilter()->match(FileName);
```

So, if `clang-tidy` wanted to report something, but chose not to because
of its location, the "Use -header-filter=..." message is printed.

### Option: `-header-filter`

If you want to see the findings that were suppressed, then follow the
instructions in the message and add:

```
-header-filter=.*
```

to the `clang-tidy` command line.

Although, I would suggest putting quotes around the `.*` part in order
to ensure that the shell does not expand it:

```
-header-filter='.*'
```

(It usually works without quotes because there will usually not be any
files in the current directory that match it as a glob expression.)

The [documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/) for this
flag says:

```
--header-filter=<string>        - Regular expression matching the names of the
                                  headers to output diagnostics from. Diagnostics
                                  from the main file of each translation unit are
                                  always displayed.
                                  Can be used together with -line-filter.
                                  This option overrides the 'HeaderFilterRegex'
                                  option in .clang-tidy file, if any.
```

Note that the message talks about `-header-filter` (one leading hyphen)
and the documentation talks about `--header-filter` (two leading
hyphens).  Both options have the same effect.

Also, be aware that many of the checks enabled by default with
`clang-tidy` do not need the `-header-filter` flag to report issues in
functions defined in header files because they also report a call site
in the primary source file.  (And if there is no call site in the
primary source file, they do not report at all, even with
`-header-filter=.*`.)

### Option: `-system-headers`

Even with `-header-filter='.*'`, the "Use -header-filter=..." message
can be produced if there is a finding in a "system" header, such as one
found via the `-isystem` search path option.  In that case, you have to
*also* pass `-system-headers` or `--system-headers`:

```
--system-headers                - Display the errors from system headers.
                                  This option overrides the 'SystemHeaders' option
                                  in .clang-tidy file, if any.
```

### Example of header filtering

I'll demonstrate these options using these files:

```
// psf.cc
#include <sys-header.h>
#include "header.h"
struct PSFClass { PSFClass(int); };
```

```
// header.h
struct HeaderClass { HeaderClass(int); };
```

```
// mysys/sys-header.h
struct SysHeaderClass { SysHeaderClass(int); };
```

Running `clang-tidy` (version 16.0.0) with the
`google-explicit-constructor` check, but only default header filters:

```
$ clang-tidy -checks='-*,google-explicit-constructor' psf.cc -- -isystem mysys
3 warnings generated.
<path>/psf.cc:4:19: warning: single-argument constructors must be marked explicit to avoid unintentional implicit conversions [google-explicit-constructor]
struct PSFClass { PSFClass(int); };
                  ^
                  explicit 
Suppressed 2 warnings (2 in non-user code).
Use -header-filter=.* to display errors from all non-system headers. Use -system-headers to display errors from system headers as well.
```

Adding `-header-filter=.*`:

```
$ clang-tidy -header-filter='.*' -checks='-*,google-explicit-constructor' psf.cc -- -isystem mysys
3 warnings generated.
<path>/header.h:2:22: warning: single-argument constructors must be marked explicit to avoid unintentional implicit conversions [google-explicit-constructor]
struct HeaderClass { HeaderClass(int); };
                     ^
                     explicit 
<path>/psf.cc:4:19: warning: single-argument constructors must be marked explicit to avoid unintentional implicit conversions [google-explicit-constructor]
struct PSFClass { PSFClass(int); };
                  ^
                  explicit 
Suppressed 1 warnings (1 in non-user code).
Use -header-filter=.* to display errors from all non-system headers. Use -system-headers to display errors from system headers as well.
```

Adding `-system-headers`:

```
$ clang-tidy -header-filter='.*' -system-headers -checks='-*,google-explicit-constructor' psf.cc -- -isystem mysys
3 warnings generated.
<path>/header.h:2:22: warning: single-argument constructors must be marked explicit to avoid unintentional implicit conversions [google-explicit-constructor]
struct HeaderClass { HeaderClass(int); };
                     ^
                     explicit 
<path>/psf.cc:4:19: warning: single-argument constructors must be marked explicit to avoid unintentional implicit conversions [google-explicit-constructor]
struct PSFClass { PSFClass(int); };
                  ^
                  explicit 
mysys/sys-header.h:2:25: warning: single-argument constructors must be marked explicit to avoid unintentional implicit conversions [google-explicit-constructor]
struct SysHeaderClass { SysHeaderClass(int); };
                        ^
```

Anomaly: on the final finding, `clang-tidy` does not print the word
`explicit` below the caret (`^`).  I don't know why.

### Message: "Found compiler error(s)."

Independent of the above, `clang-tidy` will print:

```
Found compiler error(s).
```

if the parser encountered errors in the code before reaching the stage
of running the `clang-tidy` checks.  These errors would be reported by
`clang` itself as well.

If you see this message, then `clang-tidy` is not able to fully
understand the code, so fixing these messages should be the first
priority.  Basically, work on getting `clang` to compile the code
cleanly first, *then* consider using `clang-tidy`.